# Multipeer Connectivity disconnecting and reconnecting issues

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I have implemented a simple chat application using multipeer connectivity class and everything works fine. But in the middle of chat if a user presses the back button I want to disconnect that user and get him back to the main screen. This is my current code on back press.

```
- (void)onBackTouched:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.appDelegate.mpcHandler.session disconnect];
        self.appDelegate.mpcHandler.browser=nil;
        self.appDelegate.mpcHandler.advertiser=nil;
        self.appDelegate.mpcHandler.session=nil;
        self.appDelegate.mpcHandler.peerID=nil;
    });
}
//These are the declaration of properties in my multipeer class
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MCPeerID *peerID;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MCSession *session;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MCBrowserViewController *browser;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) MCAdvertiserAssistant *advertiser;
```

This works but there is quite a lot of delay about 4-5 sec before it pops back to main screen. Another issue is when I try to connect with other users after disconnecting from earlier session without killing the app the MCBrowserViewController duplicates each device list ie its holding the info from the earlier session, is there a way to clear that? The chat application however works fine without any issues. I'm currently using iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Presumably onBackTouched is already on the main UI thread so why do you wrap your code with the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...) ?

Comment: onBackTouch is already in main queue. I was just testing if it would work, making sure that its running on main thread. But still there is delay.

Comment: Because you are running on the main thread, that's where the delay comes from. You are blocking the UI.

Comment: @AlexSu my original code did not contain dispatch_asynch(..) and issue was still there. I just added it to check if the issue would go away if I run it on the main thread.

Comment: @Gamerlegend You don't have to dispatch the code to main queue, because onBackTouch itself is already in the main queue. What you are doing is essentially dispatching to the main queue from the main queue, and that's why the problem persists. You should dispatch your disconnect code to a background queue.